# Main method not found in scanner class

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerTest{

  public static void name(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    short a[][] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    short b[][] = new short[3][3];
    System.out.println("Enter the matrix B:");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = scan.nextShort();
            
        }
    }
    short c[][] = new short[3][3];
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] +=(a[i][k]*b[k][j]);
            }
            System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }

    
   }

}
```

When I compile and run the code it says that the main method is not found in the class ScannerTest, please define the method as public static void main(String[] args). I do not know how to fix this would much appreciate if someone could point out what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Your class doesn't have a `main` method, it has a `name` method. A `main` method must be `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Apart from there being no `main` method in the code that you posted, I think that class `ScannerTest` needs to be public, as in: `public class ScannerTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**main** method represents the starting point of the program and you haven't defined the main method in the ur code snippet.
These articles will help you to understand da workflow behind the main method.
[simple program of java](https://www.javatpoint.com/simple-program-of-java)
[java main method](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-main-method)

Comment: Just realised i typed name instead of main in the static void method. I'm so stupid xd